# MCU signal processing PDM to PCM

Tags: audio, embedded, signal-processing, pcm

I would like to measure background noise - speech loudness in a room with a wireless sensor (with STM32F1 + wifi module). I bought a MEMS microphone (MP34DT01). This microphone has PDM output. 
I generate 1.4 MHz clock for the microphone, so the sampling rate is 1.4 MSample/s. I read a lot about PDM, the conclusion that I just have to use a low pass filter.

Now I read 1000 sample into a buffer array (huge overhead, because I store a bit as uint8) then I use a second order IIR Butterworth with 20kHz cutting frequency. Then I send data over TCP to my PC and draw a real-time graph.
Example code of the processing:

```
#define NZEROS 2
#define NPOLES 2
#define GAIN   5.282971791e+02

float filtered[1000] = {0}; 
uint8_t buffer[1000] = {0};
static float xv[NZEROS+1], yv[NPOLES+1];

while(1){
    //Read data from microphone
    MP34DT01_Listen(buffer);

    for(int i = 0, i<1000; i++){
       { xv[0] = xv[1]; xv[1] = xv[2]; 
         xv[2] = buffer[i] / GAIN;
         yv[0] = yv[1]; yv[1] = yv[2]; 
         yv[2] =   (xv[0] + xv[2]) + 2 * xv[1]
         + ( -0.8807871294 * yv[0]) + (  1.8732156333 * yv[1]);
         filtered[i] = yv[2];
              }
        }

    //Send data over TCP to python client
    WifiSend(filtered);
}
```

The output data doesn't correlate to the noise, I talked to the microphone, I knocked on it, but seems I process noise, neither of them appear on the graph. I tried to use moving average filter with 16 window, I tried another low pass filter, I tried 64 decimation than filter and filter than decimation.

What is the proper way to convert PDM to PCM?

Comment: What lowpass filter do you apply to your PDM (1.4MHz) signal and how do you know it's working?  Also, at what sample rate do you digitize your data?